# GMock casting to base looses mock behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, googlemock

Using a library and I'm trying to mock it in my gtests.

```
class MockScanOutcome : public Aws::DynamoDB::Model::ScanOutcome {
    public:
        MockScanOutcome() : Aws::DynamoDB::Model::ScanOutcome() {};
        MOCK_METHOD(bool, IsSuccess, (), (const));
};
```

Where the base has the following method definition:

```
template<typename R, typename E> // Result, Error
class Outcome
{
    public:

        ...

        inline bool IsSuccess() const
        {
            return this->success;
        }
}
```

I'm running the following in a test but it's coming out unequal

```
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::ScanOutcome *so = dynamic_cast<Aws::DynamoDB::Model::ScanOutcome *>(m_outcome);
    
EXPECT_CALL(*m_outcome, IsSuccess).WillOnce(Return(true));

EXPECT_EQ(m_outcome, so); //fine
EXPECT_EQ(m_outcome -> IsSuccess(), true); //fine
EXPECT_EQ(so -> IsSuccess(), true); //error
```

How do you override the const method in the base class?

Comment: This code doesn't make seance. Example test is using mock directly what is pointless. Mocks are useful to replace dependency of production code which is tested. Example doesn't call anything which looks like production code (code under testing). As a result whole question is unclear what actually is the a problem. I'm suspecting that problem is understanding how to use mocks.

Comment: This was for simplicity to explain the issue, this isn't an actual test.

Comment: Add override `(const, override)` to your MOCK_METHOD to be sure it is really virtual method.

Answer (score 2):

If your `m_outcome` is a pointer to the `mock` class, the result is right.

```
EXPECT_CALL(*m_outcome, IsSuccess).WillOnce(Return(true));
```

Expects a call in the `mock` instance, so it is ok when calling `EXPECT_EQ(m_outcome -> IsSuccess(), true);`.

```
Aws::DynamoDB::Model::ScanOutcome::IsSuccess
```

is not virtual, so when calling from a pointer to `ScanOutcome` it calls the base class function, which is not in the `EXPECT_CALL` statement and thus will return whatever it is in the `ScanOutcome::success` class member (probably an uninitialized value.)

Comment: Adding `override` to MOCK_METHOD solves most of such problems - `MOCK_METHOD(bool, IsSuccess, (), (const, override));`. Compiler tells everything then - one does not need to guess.